# Assign an id or class to a Crispy-forms input

Tags: python, django, datepicker, django-forms

I´m having a hard time with this. I have a template that renders a crispy-forms form like this:

> ```
>   <div class="box">
>      {% crispy form%}              
>   </div>
> ```

In the same template i have this javaScript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

    });
  });
</script>
```

this function is taking a class : ".datepicker". This is the code that i have in my forms.py:

```
class FacturaForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Factura 
    exclude = ("importe_Total", "iva")
    widgets = {
        'descripcion' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':3}),
        'fecha_factura': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            }
```

This way i´m trying to use a datepicker with this field "fecha_factura". But obviously is not working. This is what i have also in my forms.py:

```
helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_method = 'POST'

helper.layout = Layout(
    'tipo_Factura',
    'nombre_cliente',
    'fecha_factura',
    'numero_De_Factura',
    'descripcion',
    PrependedText('importe_sin_iva', '$'),
    FormActions(Submit('Agregar', 'Agregar', css_class= 'btn-primary'))
    )
```

So, any idea how to make this code use the javascript and display the nice datepicker?

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same situation and I didn't use the datepicker in meta, instead of that I used in layout and it works, as following:

```
    self.helper.layout = layout.Layout(
        AppendedText('start', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>', css_class="datepicker ", placeholder=_("Start")),

    )
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, one question: 'start' should be the name of my model field right?

Comment: Exactly... in your case "fecha_factura"

Comment: JUST LIKE THAT!. Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Did you set an ID value? It looks like you just gave it a class?